# How do I call a SOAP web service in Swift 2?

Tags: swift, web-services, soap, swift2

I want to call web service for Swift 2. But it never works. This is my code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    var mutableData:NSMutableData  = NSMutableData.init()
    var currentElementName:NSString = ""



    @IBOutlet var txtCelsius : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var txtFahrenheit : UITextField!


    @IBAction func actionConvert(sender : AnyObject) {
        let celcius = txtCelsius.text

        let soapMessage = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns='http://www.w3schools.com/xml/'><Celsius>\(celcius)</Celsius></CelsiusToFahrenheit></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"


        let urlString = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx"

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

        let theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)


        theRequest.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        theRequest.addValue((soapMessage), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        theRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        theRequest.HTTPBody = soapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) // or false

        let connection = NSURLConnection(request: theRequest, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
        connection!.start()


    }




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
        mutableData.length = 0;
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {
        mutableData.appendData(data)
    }


    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        let xmlParser = NSXMLParser(data: mutableData)
        xmlParser.delegate = self
        xmlParser.parse()
        xmlParser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = true

    }


    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        if currentElementName == "CelsiusToFahrenheit" {
            txtFahrenheit.text = string
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code and explain what's wrong.

Answer (score 8):

`NSURLConnection` is deprecated, use `NSURLSession` instead.

Here's an example of a function doing what you want with NSURLSession and a callback:

```
func getFarenheit(celsius celsius: Int, completion: (result: String) -> Void) {
    let soapMessage = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns='http://www.w3schools.com/xml/'><Celsius>\(celsius)</Celsius></CelsiusToFahrenheit></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
    let urlString = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx"
    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
        let theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        theRequest.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        theRequest.addValue((soapMessage), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        theRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        theRequest.HTTPBody = soapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(theRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let data = data, result = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    completion(result: result)
                }
            } else {
                print(error!.debugDescription)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Use it like this with a "trailing closure":

```
getFarenheit(celsius: 42) { (result) in
    print(result)
}
```

It prints the data containing the XML and the converted value:

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/"><CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>107.6</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult></CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code is right but i want to see 107.6 only. how can i do this?

Comment: You're welcome. My answer shows you how to fix the connection part, which was your issue. Now you have to parse the XML and for that you can continue to use NSXMLParser like you were doing - you just have to use the data coming from NSURLSession instead of the data that was coming from the NSURLConnection delegates. :)