# Soap web service xml paragraph comusmo mobile application

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, mobile, soap

where work will begin to develop a mobile application , and they already have a xml soap webservice , Swift is able to consume this data xml soap webservices ?

Comment: Yes, Swift is able to consume this data xml soap web-services.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284601/how-do-i-call-a-soap-web-service-in-swift-2

Comment: http://webindream.com/soap-with-swift/

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=swift%20xml%20soap&oq=swift%20xml%20soap&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.2998j0j7